# Invoke classes of another project without adding reference

Tags: c#, .net

I have a scenario where i need to call classes present in project B from project A. I can not add reference of B in A, due to circular reference issue.

Is there a way to call class present in another function without adding references?

Comment: If you have that situation, you need to think why is that happening and probably refactor your code.

Comment: @Pikoh you are absolutely correct, however i have 30 projects in my solution. refactoring this would take time, I have taken example of two project in my question to make it simple..

Comment: _refactoring this would take time_ - this the reason why you get in this situation

Comment: I don't think this would take a lot of time, and i think that's the best solution...

Comment: ask architect who played with you :)

Comment: @Fabio Sorry but i have tight deadline and refactoring could be done only after that..

Comment: If you will use some "hacky" workaround for this problem, then later you will face another more complex problem where you again need to think about some workarounds.

Comment: First law of software engineering:  _could be done only after that_ = never be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible and will require refactoring in perhaps one of these directions:

- Merge the two projects that 'need to reference each other' into one bigger project. Possible disadvantage: a huge project that contains too much, or has too many responsibilities, or mixing of layers (e.g. DAL, BL). Especially if it concerns more than 2 projects to begin with.
- Move conflicting parts out of proj1, 2 ... n, and into new projX. Then reference projX from proj1, 2 ... n.
- Identify `interface`s, and put them somewhere central like projX again. Make everything (or the conflicting items) in proj1, 2 ... n inherit from the interfaces. Pass objects around using interface types instead of object types.

Answer (score 0):

The key to your solution is within this: `due to circular reference issue` this means that you should separate logic to a third assembly, so you can add the references.

Comment: Absolutely, however that is not possible right now as i have 30 projects in my solution and refactoring would take time.. However my deadlines are tight.

Comment: Then you can't deliver that part on deadline, or you must move the deadline. Impossible things are impossible.

Comment: Can you merge the two assemblies into one? Every other option like reflection etc at making your problems worse.